# Developing Mobile App integrated with Facebook and Twitter using phonegap

Tags: javascript, twitter, mobile, cordova, jqtouch

currently i`m planning to create mobile app by using jQtouch and Phonegap. The application will be using Facebook and Twitter integration. Something like add new status, tweet, and seeing tweet list.
Is it possibile to create with pure javascript to do this? Or do I need some server programming like PHP to handle request and bridge my mobile app and facebook or twitter..
Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the API with standard Ajax-Requests since the same origin policy does not apply to Phonegap-Apps. If that would not be the case you could not even access your Server to bridge the requests to FB/Twitter (o:

From the Phonegap FAQ:

> Q. I want to create an application for
>   phonegap to access externally deployed
>   web services via AJAX. How can i
>   resolve the issue with the
>   cross-domain security policy of
>   XmlHttpRequest?
>
> A. The cross-domain security policy
>   does not affect PhoneGap applications.
>   Since the html files are called by
>   webkit with the file:// protocol, the
>   security policy does not apply.
>
> (in Android,you may grant
>   android.permission.INTERNET to your
>   app by edit the
>   AndroidManifest.xml)

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ

Comment: thank you..
it means that i dont need to make bridge between mymobile app and Facebook or Twitter api.. but if i create web app for it,i will need php to connect with Facebook or Twitter api instead of javascrit with ajax..
is that correct?

Comment: That's right, since normal web apps are loaded via http the same origin policy kicks in, so you would need some bridge there.